# How to show a div after form submission in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to show a div with some contents only after submission of form. For form I am using contact form 7. After submitting the form I am redirecting to this link "https://example.com/referr-mobile-app/#wpcf7-f651-o1" and here I want to display that div. Please anyone help?

Comment: are you using ajax form submission?

Comment: I think it's not an ajax form submission.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1**:

You can manage this using javascript and css.

Try out this code in your theme's js file.

```
jQuery('.wpcf7-form').prepend('<div class="form_sent_msg">Thank you for your message.</div>');
```

also add this css for show/hide the div on form sent.

```
.form_sent_msg{
    display:none;
}

.wpcf7-form.sent .form_sent_msg{
    display:block;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: try out this code for your custom post type field to insert above the form.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    add_action('wp_footer', function(){
        global $post;
        $custom_field = get_field('custom-field', $post->ID);
        ?>
        <script>
            (function ($) {
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.wpcf7-form').prepend('<div class="form_sent_msg">'+ '<?php echo $custom_field;?>' +'</div>');
              });
            })(jQuery);

        </script>
    <?php   
    });
});
```

Comment: I want show a div with some contents(custom field value).

Comment: where have your saved that field??

Comment: custom post type...In each detail page of this post have this form...

Comment: where do you want to show the div with custom field text? in contact form?

Comment: detail page of my custom post

Comment: i have updated my answer try out the update 2 code.

Comment: am i need to add this code in functions.php?

Comment: Yeah you have to add this code in your theme's functions.php file. replace `get_field('custom-field')` with your custom field name.

Comment: i want this field inside <a href=""></a> ...Is this is correct? $('.wpcf7-form').prepend('<div id="whitepaperbutton" class="whitepaperdwnldbtn"><button id="dwldwhitepaper" class="whitepaperdwnld">'+ '<a href="<?php echo $custom_field ?></a>' +'</button></div>');

Comment: I have designs in that div actually. That's why I am seeking a solution to display the div with contents after form submitted successfully

Comment: <div class="Download-Paper" id="whitepapernoneed">
<h2>Download White Paper</h2>
<div class="saccess-form">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="651" title="Download Whitepaper"]')?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="whitepaperbutton" class="whitepaperdwnldbtn">
<h3>Thank you for registering</h3>
<?php 
$goody_file = get_field('whitepaper_pdf');
?>
<button id="dwldwhitepaper" class="whitepaperdwnld">
<a href="<?php echo $goody_file ?>" download >Download The White Paper</a>
</button>
</div>

Comment: this is the div i want to display.